# Main class won't read the other one, project inserted using SVN

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I'm loading an Eclipse project using SVN on my PC and after importing it and setting up the build path, my Main method won't recognize the other one no matter what I try.

I've tried different Build Paths, Refreshing the project, Cleaning it... nothing seems to work. I've also tried manually implementing the class, but had no luck.

This is my Main class:

```
package app;

public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MainFrame mf = new MainFrame();
        mf.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This is MainFrame class:
    package app;

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame
{

    private static MainFrame instance;

    public MainFrame() 
    {
        Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension screenD = tk.getScreenSize();
        int sHeight = screenD.height;
        int sWidth = screenD.width;
        setSize(sWidth / 2, sHeight / 2);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);    
    }

    static 
    {
        instance = new MainFrame();
        System.out.println("Proba");
    }

    public static MainFrame getInstance() 
    {
        return instance;
    }

}
```

I will include screenshots below as well.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `app.MainFrame` is exclued from the *Java Build Path* as you can see from the editor icon which has an outline *J* instead of a normal *J*.

**Right-click** the **`MainFrame.java`** file and choose ***Build Path > Add to Build Path***.